# Jack type for a 12v DC motor

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, coax

I have an Arduino with a motor shield and I use it to power 4 different DC motors.
Motors are connected to the shield through a screw terminal.
Since I am in the prototyping step, I am moving them around a lot, connecting and disconnecting them all the time, which means screwing and unscrewing the wires every time.

I was looking for a jack, so I can easily plug in-out. I was going to use the standard 2.1 X 5.5 mm coaxial power connector, however I'm wandering if there is anything smaller.
The flowing power shouldn't be very intense, it's a 12v with a peak usage just little above 1A.

Comment: "clamp that tights the wires" sounds like a description of a *screw terminal*

Comment: the standard 2.1mm jack is actually perfect for multiple insertions and 1A.  What's not right about it?

Comment: they are big, or better, very long! the whole shield has the size of a credit card, female + male connector are the same size of 50% of the shield. there isn't anything smaller?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using spade terminals along with a spade terminal block (or better yet, make one using the reciprocal of your spade pairs)

[image]
<sub>(source: [electronicplus.com](http://www.electronicplus.com/images/products/S-8202-3.jpg))</sub>

+

[image]
<sub>(source: [alibaba.com](http://img.alibaba.com/wsphoto/v0/361731849/Brand-New-Red-22-16AWG-Insulated-Female-Spade-Terminal-Connectors-Wholesale-EP144-.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you for adding the citations for the images. That courtesy (and sometimes legal obligation) is often overlooked here.